# PouchDB in a web worker on iOS : is there a viable solution as of today?

Tags: ios, cordova, web-worker, pouchdb

The title says it all: we have a Cordova / Ionic 3 app which uses a local PouchDB to enable offline use. The app also uses a web worker to benefit from multithreading and keep the UI smooth, especially because we use d3.js to render some of the views. 
What we've tried so far :

- web worker in a separate file : we haven't been able to find a PouchDB adapter (in-memory is not an option) that would work properly in UIWebView or WKWebView
- web worker as a blob URL : we tried the [worker-pouch](https://github.com/pouchdb-community/worker-pouch) utility by Nolan Lawson on UIWebView, which actually worked well... Until we realized (after the app was published on the App Store !) that the app would crash on startup on some devices, with a **WebCore: Worker: EXC_BAD_ACCESS** error which seems to be related to the webkit method **WebCore::SerializedScriptValue::writeBlobsToDiskForIndexedDB**. This happens on iPhones or iPads, running iOS 10.x or 11.x.

We've spent quite a few days trying to find our best option here, and while we've found many reports about the situation in 2016 (kudos to Mr Lawson), we cannot seem to find a viable option as of today.

Has any of you had a successfull experience (s)he'd like to share ? (WKWebView ideally, but UIWebView would also do :)

Cheers

Comment: Hi, have you found a solution to this? Sharing your findings would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: Hi, I'm still struggling with this unfortunately. I'll give PouchDB 6.4.3 a try soon, as it should improve IDB support on iOS, but I don't know if this will also improve web worker compatibility. I'll update my post with my findings anyway... I really wonder how people do PWAs on iOS for now.